# Error 450001 when using makeCall in PJSUA2

Tags: c#, voip, pjsip, pjsua2, windows-phone-voip

I want to create softphone application using pjsua2.

When I use `makeCall` funtion, I'm facing this problem:

> System.ApplicationException: 'C++ pj::Error:
>
> Title:       pjsua_call_make_call(acc.getId(), &pj_dst_uri, param.p_opt, this, param.p_msg_data, &id)
>
> Code:        450001
>
> Description: Erreur externe indéfinie.

connection with the server is good

My code :

```
MyCall call = new MyCall(acc,-1);
CallOpParam prm = new CallOpParam(true); 
            
call.makeCall("destination", prm);
```

```
public class MyCall : Call {

    public  MyCall(Account acc, int id) : base(acc, id) {}

    public virtual void onCallState(OnCallStateParam prm) {
        base.onCallState(prm);
        CallInfo ci = getInfo();
        MessageBox.Show("Call state: " + ci.stateText);
    }

    public virtual void onCallMediaState(OnCallMediaStateParam prm) { 
        base.onCallMediaState(prm);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code 450001 means 'the application cannot access to the microphone" (usually due system privacy settings). Trying to access the microphone is contained in 'base.onCallMediaState(prm)', probably.  Check your system settings and implement a processing of this case in your application.